# How to change a file in /etc inside a docker container using dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker application, I want to append the word "Hellow" to the passwd file inside the docker container. I made this change to Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "Hellow" >> /etc/passwd
```

But the word Hellow is not showing after I run cat /etc/passwd by using `docker exec -u 0 -it my_php-apache_1 bash` and then `cat /etc/passwd` command.

Comment: you have to build the docker image with the new instruction, i believe.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't building it.